# When Is forward<T> equivalent to forward<decltype(Targ)> ?

Tags: c++, c++14, perfect-forwarding

Say I want to have a generic higher order function. The most common ways to do it are :

### A. Generic lambda

```
auto F1 = [](auto f) { /*...*/ }
```

### B. Function template

```
template<class F> auto F2(F&& f) { /*...*/ }
```

My question is on **how to use** `f` inside the higher order functions. While there's only one way to do it in case A :

```
std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)(...);
```

there are at least two ways in case B :

```
std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)(...); 
std::forward<F>(f)(...);
```

Are these ways equivalent and if not what are some examples of "tie breaking" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, the declarations for case A and case B are not the same. Case B can deduce an lvalue or rvalue reference, but case A only deduces a value type. `auto` deduces similarly to a template argument, so change `auto` to `auto&&` for the declarations to match.

To answer your question, they *are* equivalent. The only difference is that reference collapsing takes place in case B. `decltype(f)` will invariably be a reference while `F` will be a value type when the argument passed to `F2` is an rvalue:

```
F2(<lvalue>); decltype(f) == T&,  F == T&
F2(<rvalue>); decltype(f) == T&&, F == T
```

This doesn't matter to `std::forward`, because reference collapsing will always produce the right type.

```
template< class T >
constexpr T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t );
```

If `T` is `F&&`, then the return type remains `T&&` because `T&& && == T&&`. If `T` is simply an `F` (value type) then the return type is still the same (`T && == T&&`). The reference collapsing rules can be found on [this site](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html).

TLDR: There's no effective difference because reference collapsing produces the same type.

Answer (score 3):

Let's walk through what is happening when you call your `F2` with different types of arguments - an rvalue reference, a const lvalue reference and non-const lvalue reference. Let's not discuss the `volatile` as it basically adds no new information (it behaves just like `const` or `const volatile`) and assume you pass different `int`s for simplicity sake.

First, the type for `F` is deduced:

- If you pass `int&&`, `F` will be `int`, but (`decltype(f) == int&&`).
- If you pass `const int&`, `F` will be `const int&` (`decltype(f) == const int&`)
- If you pass `int&`, `F` will be `int&` (`decltype(f) == int&`)

(See Scott Meyers' [blog](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU) or [slides](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/C++TypeDeductionandWhyYouCareCppCon2014.pdf) for a comprehensive explanation).

So as you can see for the latter two cases, `decltype(f) == F` so there's not much to analyse further. However, for the first case they are different, so let's look deeper into that.

You then pass either `F` or `decltype(f)` to `std::forward` as a template parameter. `std::forward` [takes in](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) a `std::remove_reference<T>&` or `std::remove_reference<T>&&` so the parameter type will be the same in both cases. However, the return type might potentially be different (because we pass in different `T` for it - `int` and `int&&`). However, due to reference collapsing performed by the compiler (again, see Scott's explanation for details), `int&& &&` becomes simply `int&&`. So the return value is also the same.

To sum up, there's no difference if you use either `decltype(f)` or `F` for `std::forward`.

Also, here's some [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b641b918a3c679aa) example which shows all the deduced types even for such a useless (yet valid) beast as `const volatile int &&`.